# Extjs4.2 rtl is causing huge problems in IE6

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

So recently me and the developer team I'm in have finished working on a huge project for transforming our entire system from Extjs2 to 4.2.

We have finished fixing everything, every little bug, except we were left with one little task, making the system also available for IE6 (many of our customers still use it). What we thought was a little task was apparently one big problem.

None of the grids were loaded properly (only column headers and no data), and many important components such as panels appeared blank.

We apply the rtl property in our main css file, since we don't want to add `rtl: true` for every component:

`html { direction: rtl }`

Once removing this, everything was working perfectly (except for the direction of course). Currently we are following the code in ext-all-rtl-debug and finding the problems one by one (for example we found out that an added cls in the mask function was causing some of the problems with the grid). As you can imagine, this is  a big, painful and slow process (especially considering we debug ie6).

Although everything looks fine in FF, Chrome, and even IE7, the entire project have rendering problems in IE6.

If anyone is familiar with the issue, and perhaps know of a possible fix, we would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The "rtl:true" config is inherited throughout the component hierarchy, you should be able to just add "rtl: true" to the top-level component in the hierarchy (usually the viewport).  This  eliminates any need to set "direction:rtl" yourself, since components in an rtl hierarchy will have the "x-rtl" class added to their element(s).

You also need to make sure you are using the rtl stylesheet, as Ext JS components require quite a bit of special styling to work correctly in rtl mode.  For example, for the classic theme this would be: ext-theme-classic-all-rtl.css

If you're still stuck, have a look at this example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/rtl/rtl.html?theme=classic

Comment: I know that, but it seems that our components are just not working in IE6. Anyway, after a lot of discussion it was decided that we abandon our work on IE6 since it was too much time consuming. Right now we are just forcing everybody to use Chrome for our system :)